# Searching rails and then returning a Yes or No if it exists in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, search

How do I search my rails model 'Locality' and then return: "Yes" - if the search exists or "No" if the value the user has entered into the search bar is not in the database?

Here's the search bar so far:

```
<%= form_tag localities_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This is the code that I've tried to see weather it exists in the database and it works but only for the value in the () not what the user entered in the search bar.

```
<% if Locality.exists?(12423) %>
    No
<% else %>
    Yes
<% end %>
```

Also here is the model file:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['postcode LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in the controller:

```
localities = Locality.where("search ILIKE ?", params[:search])
localities.any? ? @result = "YES" : @result = "NO"
```

Comment: Thanks a nice and simple solution